# how to test rails custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, rspec

I have a custom validation that checks whether a param is valid JSON or not:

```
 def is_valid_json
    begin
      !!JSON.parse(preferences)
    rescue
      errors.add(:preferences, "This is not valid JSON")
    end
  end
```

In my controller test, I want to make sure that when I send in a bad value, the status code of the response is 422. Here is the spec from my controller:

```
  it 'should return a 422 when validations fail' do
    put :update, {:user_preferences => { :email => @email, :preferences => 'badval' } }
    expect(response.status).to eq(422)
    res = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(res['error']).to_not be_blank
  end
```

The test fails due to an error:

```
Failure/Error: put :update, {:user_preferences => { :email => @email, :preferences => 'badval' } }
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
Validation failed: Preferences This is not valid JSON
```

Controller code:

```
 def update
    @user_preference = UserPreference.where(email: params[:user_preferences][:email]).first
    authorize! :update, @user_preference
    @user_preference.update_attributes!(params[:user_preferences])
    render_api_response(@user_preference)
  end
```

When I make the request from the browser, I get a 422 return status code, so is there a reason that I can't get the same result from the test?

Comment: can you add the controller code and the way you initialize the record at your test env as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, `update_attributes` raises an exception, and you need to catch that. Perhaps you are doing an XHR call with your browser and you code handles that exception code (422) in the front end. For tests to work you should rescue the exception and respond with the relevant status in your render

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do
  render json: {
    error: "Invalid params",
    status: 422
    },
    status: 422
end
```